# How to use 7z and "for file" with multiple file inputs?

Tags: bash, files, for, 7z

I have multiple files in a folder like:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
...
100.txt
```

And I want to use 7z to compress single files, generating 1.7z, 2.7z 3.7z...
I'm trying to use this:

```
for file in {1..100} ./{1..100}.txt; do 7z a $file; done
```

But with no luck.

Alternatively, is there a way to automatic use the txt names?

Comment: The cheap and dirty way to do it would be to have your target archives look like `1.txt.7z` instead of `1.7z`.  I'm sure you could script something using `basename file .txt` if you're not cheap and dirty

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is likely

```
for file in {1..100}; do 7z a "$file.7z" "$file.txt"; done
```

Alternatively, you could use *parameter expansion* of the form `${var%suf}` to remove the suffix e.g.

```
for file in {1..100}.txt; do 7z a "${file%.txt}.7z" "$file"; done
```